# Как собрать кластер (HPC)? И что с ним делать?

Tags: hpc, кластер

Интересно как оно работает, на чем собрать (в частности из чего) и что после этого с ним можно делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, можно взять пару десятков тачек на ксеонах. А потом обсчитывать и моделировать ядерные реакции или анализировать геном человека. А ещё можно анализировать звёздные снимки, а потом строить трёхмерную модель галактики. А ещё можно анализировать радиосигналы из космоса в надежде, что удастся обнаружить искусственные сигналы. И вообще много чего ещё можно.

**UPD**
Если вы имели в виду софт, то разумеется он должен быть для этого предназначен. Следует смотреть в сторону MPI. Например, [Oracle (Sun) MPI](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/message-passing-toolkit-070499.html).

Вот несколько ссылок по теме:

- [CRAY XE6](http://www.cray.com/Products/XE/CrayXE6System.aspx)
- [Другие решения CRAY](http://www.cray.com/Products/Products.aspx)
- [Dell HPC System online constructor](http://advisors.dell.com/AdvisorWeb/Advisor.aspx?advisor=d6676576-1bfb-4ce1-b8ca-2e976b02575d&c=us&l=en&cs=555)
- [Linux HPC Cluster Installation](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246041.html)
- [Кое какие кусочки HPC-решений от IBM](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/deepcomputing/)

Comment: Cool)))