# Ubuntu Cloud

Tags: облако, кластер, ubuntu

Нужно поставить софт на сервер IBM x3200 M3 (точнее пока не знаю) и 20 компов с процами AMD Phenom II x6 3200GHz для учебно-исследовательской работы в сфере математики. Рассматриваем разные решения. Одна из задач: допустим, нужно решать вычислительно сложную задачу, в такие моменты хочется чтобы все 10-20 клиентских компьютеров помогали одинокому серверу в вычислениях.
Вопрос:
Подойдёт ли для такой задачи Ubuntu Cloud?
А поточнее:
Можно ли (и как, если можно) настроить такие пакеты как матлаб для совместной работы в облаке? Какие задачи сейчас решаются в системах такого рода? Какие приложения вообще можно будет запускать? Как вообще происходит процесс работы в облачных системах? Все говорят про облачные вычисления, пишут мануалы как развернуть своё облако, но очень сложно найти, что вообще потом с ним делать? Ещё слышал, многие задаются вопросом, можно ли поставить виртуальную Windows для пользователей поверх облака. Можно? И что из этого выйдет?

UPD: В данный момент планируется поставить на клиентские машины Linux + Windows параллельно. Есть такая библиотечка - MPI. Она существует и для обоих семейств ОС. Отсюда ещё пара вопросов по теме: Нормально ли оно будет работать, если часть машин в кластере будет на Windows, а часть на Linux? Опять же, какие задачи можно распределять с использованием этой библиотеки? В общем то, что это возможно, написано здесь: [mpich-discuss](https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/mailman/htdig/mpich-discuss/2010-June/007377.html).

Несколько накопанных ссылок про облака: [Как создать облачный сервер с помощью Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud](http://domaintimes.net/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-ub/); и ещё: [ubuntu-it](http://help.ubuntu-it.org/10.04/ubuntu/serverguide/it/uec.html).

UDP2:
Я вот проглядел в первый раз, а сейчас нашёл [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4977/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-hpc-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) на этом ресурсе на эту же тему. Есть один ответ. Он хороший, но хотелось бы поконкретнее узнать про ПО и остальные освещённые мной здесь вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю,  Ubuntu Cloud использует обычный [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/), поэтому, если будете разбираться подойдет любая информация по нему.  В качестве альтернативы можно обратить внимание на AWS, Google Engine и MS Azure. Все они имеют тестовый период, которого должно хватить для того, чтобы понять что вам нужно.

И да, действительно, для того, чтобы использовать вычислительные ресурсы облака нужно писать/использовать код, который написан специальным образом, что позволит хорошо его горизонтально масштабировать.  Один из наиболее известных паттернов разработки подобных алгоритмов:  [Map and Reduce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Answer (score 0):

Я мало шарю в облаках пока что, но то что вы пытаетесь сделать - высокопроизводительный кластер (возможно облако есть что-то аналогичное).

[Тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)) можно найти информацию о кластерах.

Сам копал какое-то время в этом направлении. Хотел найти что-то для рендеринга и возможно виртуализации. Пока не было времени этим заняться, поэтому буду следить за темой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, честно говоря я не очень понимаю разницу между кластером и облаком :)  
Вообще, теорию в целом я читал и понимаю, что суть такое эти кластеры. Мне не понятно, какие конкретно задачи я смогу решать с ними.
И как это будет выглядеть? Допустим, я установил матлаб на целый кластер - что это значит для пользователя? Насколько я понял, это будет выглядеть как будто кластер - одна машина и на ней запускается приложение. Ну значит должен быть какой-то тонкий клиент для кластера - тогда как он выглядит?
И ещё было замечательно где-нибудь надыбать список примеров использования.

Comment: Насколько я помню либо имеется клиент к ПО либо идет доступ через терминал на контроллер кластера.