# Ubuntu Cloud

Tags: облако, кластер, ubuntu, виртуализация

Нужно поставить софт на сервер IBM x3200 M3 (точнее пока не знаю) и 20 компов с процами AMD Phenom II x6 3200GHz для учебно-исследовательской работы в сфере математики. Рассматриваем разные решения. Одна из задач: допустим, нужно решать вычислительно сложную задачу, в такие моменты хочется чтобы все 10-20 клиентских компьютеров помогали одинокому серверу в вычислениях.  Вопрос:  Подойдёт ли для такой задачи Ubuntu Cloud?  А поточнее:  Можно ли (и как, если можно) настроить такие пакеты как матлаб для совместной работы в облаке? Какие задачи сейчас решаются в системах такого рода? Какие приложения вообще можно будет запускать? Как вообще происходит процесс работы в облачных системах? Все говорят про облачные вычисления, пишут мануалы как развернуть своё облако, но очень сложно найти, что вообще потом с ним делать? Ещё слышал, многие задаются вопросом, можно ли поставить виртуальную Windows для пользователей поверх облака. Можно? И что из этого выйдет?  UPD: В данный момент планируется поставить на клиентские машины Linux + Windows параллельно. Есть такая библиотечка - MPI. Она существует и для обоих семейств ОС. Отсюда ещё пара вопросов по теме: Нормально ли оно будет работать, если часть машин в кластере будет на Windows, а часть на Linux? Опять же, какие задачи можно распределять с использованием этой библиотеки? В общем то, что это возможно, написано здесь: [mpich-discuss][1].    Несколько накопанных ссылок про облака: [Как создать облачный сервер с помощью Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud][2]; и ещё: [ubuntu-it][3].  UDP2:Я вот проглядел в первый раз, а сейчас нашёл [вопрос][4] на этом ресурсе на эту же тему. Есть один ответ. Он хороший, но хотелось бы поконкретнее узнать про ПО и остальные освещённые мной здесь вопросы.  [1]: https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/mailman/htdig/mpich-discuss/2010-June/007377.html  [2]: http://domaintimes.net/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-ub/  [3]: http://help.ubuntu-it.org/10.04/ubuntu/serverguide/it/uec.html  [4]: [Как собрать кластер (HPC)? И что с ним делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4977/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-hpc-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По описанию вашей задачи, вам скорее подойдет кластер, а не облако. Основная задача облака - это выделение ресурса по требованию, то есть сглаживание случайных пиковых нагрузок. А задача кластера запланированное разделение вычислительной нагрузки.

Для начала стоит попробовать [кластер Rocks](http://www.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/base/5.4.3/). Работа с ним может оказаться проще, чем с Ubuntu Cloud.

Comment: Спасибо, если Вы имели дело с таким кластером, не могли бы прояснить пару моментов?1) Какой интерфейс у пользователя в таком кластере?2) Могут ли с ним работать одновременно несколько человек с разных терминалов?3) И последний вопрос на засыпку: а можно к вычислениям кластера подключить и GPU клиентов? Создаётся впечатление, что нам купили игровые компьютеры :))